# count the number of rows of each table (where table names are returned from subquery )

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am doing a query from  a table which gives list of tables (based on different conditions list will be different).
I want to show list of tablenames and their row count. How can i achieve this?

I have tried

```
select count(*) from (select tablename from main_table) as t;
```

But it just return the count of entries in main_table but not the count of entries in each table.
I can use system tables to get rowcount but I don't want all tables but specific tables and may need row count of specific queries.

Algo is something like this

```
for tablenames in main_table where id>3:
    select count(*) from tablename where constraints
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply query the metadata:

```
SELECT  Table_Name, table_rows
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE   TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND     TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourDatabase';
```

Or alternatively you will need to use a `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT  'T1' AS TableName, COUNT(*) AS Rows
FROM    T1
UNION ALL
SELECT  'T2' AS TableName, COUNT(*) AS Rows
FROM    T2
UNION ALL
SELECT  'T3' AS TableName, COUNT(*) AS Rows
FROM    T3;
```

If this needs to be dynamically done then you could use dynamic SQL:

```
SET @SQL = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT ''', 
                                TableName, 
                                ''' AS TableName, COUNT(*) AS Rows FROM ', 
                                TableName SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
            FROM MainTable
            --WHERE Some condition to limit tables
            );

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6911/33)**

This essentially produces the same SQL as the `UNION ALL` solution, but creates the SQL based on the contents of your main table.

Comment: It was correct answer as I did not want to access information schema. I was trying to do it in monetdb but it does not allow to pass table names dynamically so I had to send to queries first to retrieve the table names then making their union all queries

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT table_name, table_type, SUM(TABLE_ROWS) 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'db5' -- or your own schema
    AND  table_type ='BASE TABLE'
    AND table_name LIKE 'mytables%'
GROUP BY table_name, table_type
```

Or this

```
SELECT table_name, TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{your_db}';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example with dynamic SQL, if you want to create table with three columns:
1st is `Table Name` and contains table names of main_table, 2nd is `Column X`, contain single quote (‘) char(s) in column `User Name` of main_table and 3rd is `Rows` which contains count of rows of each table in `Table Name`:

```
    SET @SQL = (select GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT ''', 
                                    `Table Name `,
                                    ''' AS `Table Name`,
                                    ', quote(`User Name`), ',
                                    COUNT(*) AS Rows FROM `',
                                    `Table Name` SEPARATOR '` UNION ALL ')
                                    FROM `.tables`
               );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: why have you written two answers??

Answer (score -1):

if choose dynamic SQL, and there some column name contain empty space the error is occur. In this case only works metadata through INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES (if you have rights to use it), but not dynamic SQL query!
Presume that you have table, and that table have column name `Table Name` which contains the names (with spaces) of existing others tables.
If you want to use dynamic SQL and there are some column names with empty spaces the correct query is:

```
    SET @SQL = (select GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT ''', 
                                `Table Name`,
                                ''' AS `Table Name`,
                                COUNT(*) AS Rows FROM `',
                                `Table Name` SEPARATOR '` UNION ALL ')
            FROM main_table
            );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.